# How can i open all swagger api in one chrome tab?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I'm working on Visual studio c# ASP.NET 6 and I work on several API, when I start my application, all theses API (swagger) are opening in different tabs. What I want is, when I'm starting my app, i want all the swagger opening in the same tab and not as many as I have API.

I've search on different website, I've ask to chat GPT, he tolds me to put this in my program.cs in each api i had but it doesn't worked.

```
c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems["deepLinking"] = "true";
```

Comment: Do you want [something like this](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents)? The resulting Swagger UI page will [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcvfG.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in visual studio:

- Tools
- options
- Project and Solutions
  - Web Projects
  There, unbox "Stop Debugger when browser window is closed, close browser when debugging stops"